# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'のエラーについて

Tags: python, 機械学習

現在、Python機械学習プログラミング 達人データサイエンティストによる理論と実装の本で勉強してまして、
コードを実装すると、下記のエラーが発生してしまいます。ネットで調べたところ、numpyでarrayを追加することで解決とのことですが、どのようなコードを追加すればよいのか分かりません。
コードの追加及び他の方法で解決することについて、ご教示よろしくお願いいたします。

```
weights, params = [], []
for c in np.arange(-5, 5):
    lr = LogisticRegression(C=10.**c, random_state=0) 
    lr.fit(X_train_std, y_train)
    
    weights.append(lr.coef_[1])
    
    params.append(10.**c)
    
    weights = np.array(weights)
    
    plt.plot(params, weights[:, 0], label='petal lenght')
    plt.plot(params, weights[:, 1], linestyle='--', label='petal width')
    plt.ylabel('weight coefficient')
    plt.xlabel('C')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.show()
```

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-037561b182ec> in <module>
      4     lr.fit(X_train_std, y_train)
      5 
----> 6     weights.append(lr.coef_[1])
      7 
      8     params.append(10.0**c)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
​
```

Comment: エラーが出る直前で、変数weightsの型はndarrayになっており、appendメソッドが使用できていないようです。一旦kernelをrestartしても同じエラーがでますか？

Comment: 質問に書かれているのは、プログラムの一部分だと思われます。変数 weightsを宣言している部分を含め、全体が判るプログラムを質問に挿入してもらえませんか？

Comment: その2行下のコードで`weights = np.array(weights)`しているので、`weights`は`for`ループの初回はPythonのリストであっても、ループの2回目以後は`numpy.array`になってしまっているのでは？ ちなみに書籍のどのページの課題なのか追記すると助言や回答が得られ易いかもしれません。

Comment: [python-machine-learning-book-2nd-edition ch03](https://github.com/rasbt/python-machine-learning-book-2nd-edition/blob/master/code/ch03/ch03.py#L440)

Comment: ホーリー様
コメントありがとうございます。

コメント通り、一旦kernelをrestartを実施しましたが、同様なエラーが発生しました。

Comment: Fumu様
コメントありがとうございます。

weightsを宣言してるコードらしきはありませんでした。

その前は、シグモイド関数を定義してまして、次にこの記載したコードになっています。

Comment: kunif様
コメントありがとうございます。

書籍は65ページの3.3 ロジスティクス回帰を使ったクラスの確率のモデリングというところです。

コメントに記載してある、numpy.arrayですが、この書籍ではnumpy配列に変換されており、おそらくnumpy.arrayになっているのだと思います。

Answer (score 1):

forループの中で、変数weightsがlistからndarrayに変換されているため、2回めのループ以降に上記のエラーが出ているものと思われます。したがって、下記のようにfor文が終了したところでlistのweightsをndarrayに変換して実行してみたらどうでしょうか。手元で試していないので参考に留めてください。

```
weights, params = [], []
for c in np.arange(-5, 5):
    lr = LogisticRegression(C=10.**c, random_state=0) 
    lr.fit(X_train_std, y_train)
    
    weights.append(lr.coef_[1])
    
    params.append(10.**c)
    
weights = np.array(weights)
    
plt.plot(params, weights[:, 0], label='petal lenght')
plt.plot(params, weights[:, 1], linestyle='--', label='petal width')
plt.ylabel('weight coefficient')
plt.xlabel('C')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    
plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。

具体的にどのようにweightsをndarrayに変換すればよろしいでしょうか？
先ほど、weightsをndarrayに変更して、実行してみましたがエラーが発生してしまいました。

Comment: 上記の回答のコードにあるように、`weights = np.array(weights)`でndarrayになっていると思います。エラー内容はどのようなものでしたか？

Comment: 本日再度、実装したところ問題なく実行できました。
先日まではエラーが発生していたのですが,,,,


エラー内容記載せずに申し訳ございません。
エラーは上記のエラーと同じものが発生してました。

Comment: 追加で、コードは以前エラーが発生したコードで実装してみました。