# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'のエラーが出てしまいます。

Tags: python

プログラミングを始めたばかりの初心者です。
画像診断のプログラムを組みたいのですが、下記のようなエラーが出てしまいます。
google colaboratoryを使用しており、kaggleのChest X-Ray Images (Pneumonia)というデータセットから何枚かgoogleドライブにアップロードして使おうとしています。
他の方の質問も見てみましたが、理解が追い付かず...
解決方法を教えていただければ幸いです。
（appendの代わりにnp.appendを入れたりしましたが、そちらでもエラーが出てしまいました。）

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import glob

x_train = []
y_train = []
x_test = []
y_test = []

for f in glob.glob("/content/drive/MyDrive/kaggle/image/*/*/*.jpeg"):
    img_data = tf.io.read_file(f)
    img_data = tf.io.decode_jpeg(img_data)
    img_data = tf.image.resize(img_data,(100,100))
  
    if f.split("/")[6]=="train":
        x_train.append(img_data)
        y_train.append(int(f.split("/")[7].split("_")[0]))
    elif f.split("/")[6]=="test":
          x_test.append(img_data)
          y_test.append(int(f.split("/")[7].split("_")[0]))
    
    x_train = np.array(x_train) / 255.0
    y_train = np.array(y_train)
    x_test = np.array(x_test) / 255.0
    y_test = np.array(y_test)
```

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-44f0c41d960e> in <module>()
     18         y_train.append(int(f.split("/")[7].split("_")[0]))
     19     elif f.split("/")[6]=="test":
---> 20           x_test.append(img_data)
     21           y_test.append(int(f.split("/")[7].split("_")[0]))
     22 

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: 何かお手本にした記事があれば、それとの差を調べてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: コメントと質問の編集ありがとうございます！
コード全体はYouTubeのデータサイエンス塾‼さんのディープラーニングの動画を参考に作りました。
差というと、データがカラーではなくグレースケールであることくらいなのですが…

Answer (score 1):

紹介された動画のコーディング作業画像を良く見ると、ほんの一瞬ですが該当部分のインデントを減らして`for`ループの外に移動させていました。
`19:00`・`20:26`付近や`21:52`以後など

なので、以下の部分のインデントを解除して`for`ループの外に移動すれば動作するでしょう。

```
    x_train = np.array(x_train) / 255.0
    y_train = np.array(y_train)
    x_test = np.array(x_test) / 255.0
    y_test = np.array(y_test)
```

単純にこちらのようにする。

```
x_train = np.array(x_train) / 255.0
y_train = np.array(y_train)
x_test = np.array(x_test) / 255.0
y_test = np.array(y_test)
```

---

以下は動画が紹介される前のソースコードだけで推測した内容です。
一応何か別の現象が起こった時などのための注意事項として残しておきます。

---

お手本の記事へのリンクとかソースコードの情報が追加されるかどうか分かりませんが、今のソースコードからすると、問題の原因は以下のコードによりPythonの基本的なリストとして定義された変数がnumpy.ndarrayに変換されてしまったことですね。
例えばこちらの記事と類似の現象です。
['numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'のエラーについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/69976/26370)

リストとしての宣言と初期化

```
x_train = []
y_train = []
x_test = []
y_test = []
```

forループでの処理でndarrayに変換される

```
    x_train = np.array(x_train) / 255.0
    y_train = np.array(y_train)
    x_test = np.array(x_test) / 255.0
    y_test = np.array(y_test)
```

なので、forループの初回は以下の処理は正常に動作しますが、2回目以後はリストでは無くndarrayになっているのでエラーになります。

```
    if f.split("/")[6]=="train":
        x_train.append(img_data)
        y_train.append(int(f.split("/")[7].split("_")[0]))
    elif f.split("/")[6]=="test":
          x_test.append(img_data)
          y_test.append(int(f.split("/")[7].split("_")[0]))
```

最初からndarrayとして宣言・初期化しnp.appendを使うか、ループ後半のリスト全体をndarrayに変換してしまう処理を見直して必要なデータだけndarrayに変換するよう書き変えるか、のどちらかになると思われます。

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ThKRS7B5GFY
参考にさせていただいたのはこちらの動画です。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。最初からndarrayとして宣言する場合、どのように書き換えればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: @maimai さん、動画を良く見るとインデントを直した部分があり、それを見落としたのでしょう。なので当初回答のndarrayによる宣言・処理は関係無くなりました。

Comment: 本当でした！インデントが違いましたね、お恥ずかしい限りです…お手数おかけして申し訳ありませんでした。

Comment: 度々の質問で申し訳ないのですが、インデントを直して動かしてみたところcould not broadcast input array from shape (100,100,1) into shape (100,100)というエラーが出てしまいました。おそらくグレースケールの画像を使用したからだと思いますが、直し方がわかりません

Comment: 新しい現象ですし、コメントではどの行で発生したかとか表示されている情報の一部しか転記されていないため良く分かりませんね。この質問は終了/承認して新規に質問を起こしてください。